Wifi sporadiclly keeps disconnecting
so i recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my 2017 MacBook Air. Works like a charm, but i have a problem using it with my home wifi. I have another laptop, also with an Ubuntu install, where i have no similar issues. So when i boot up my MacBook, the wifi is connected in infact seems to work. The Wifi icon in the top right corner shows that its connected, and during that, i can access the web. But after a certain time, websites will stop loading. The icon in the top right corner will switch to a empty wifi icon with three dots in it. When i then go into the wifi settings, the network will disconnect and there will be a spinning loading icon next to it, but there wont happen anything, after a few seconds it will just stop. If i switch wifi off and wait a few seconds, i sometines reconnects for a few seconds, befor repeating the descriped behavior. The weird thing is, it doesnt do this in any other Network. For example, at my uni, it just stays at the wifi and works constantly. Even at the second wifi network at my home (I have set up different networks for the upper and lower floors of my house, but they all lead to the same router), downstairs, it just works. I tried to reinstall the network drivers already, didnt fix it. The only thing on who to get it working again, is to reboot the laptop.
Does anyone has an idea on how to fix this?
Regarding the output of the first prompt waltinator provided, its quite a chunk of text, like 550 lines, including my ip and mac adresses which i dont feel comfortable posting here lol, it exeeds the character limit.
The service NetworkManager status output reads as follows:
 NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-08-08 20:53:47 CEST; 19min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1447 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 9329)
     Memory: 17.6M (peak: 33.5M)
        CPU: 2.319s
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1447 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Aug 08 21:03:28 MoritzMacBook NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1723143808.1234] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=Removed the IP, acd pending
Aug 08 21:03:28 MoritzMacBook NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1723143808.3006] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed new lease, address=Removed the IP
Aug 08 21:03:28 MoritzMacBook NetworkManager[1447]: <info>  [1723143808.3016] policy: set 'It hurts when IP' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug 08 21:03:28 MoritzMacBook NetworkManager[1447]: <info>

The service --status-all promt reads as follows:
 [ + ]  alsa-utils
 [ - ]  anacron
 [ + ]  apparmor
 [ + ]  apport
 [ + ]  atop
 [ + ]  atopacct
 [ + ]  binfmt-support
 [ + ]  bluetooth
 [ - ]  console-setup.sh
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  cups
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  gdm3
 [ - ]  grub-common
 [ + ]  kerneloops
 [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  openvpn
 [ - ]  plymouth
 [ + ]  plymouth-log
 [ + ]  procps
 [ - ]  rsync
 [ - ]  saned
 [ - ]  speech-dispatcher
 [ - ]  spice-vdagent
 [ - ]  sssd
 [ + ]  sysstat
 [ + ]  tlp
 [ + ]  ufw
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ - ]  uuidd
 [ - ]  whoopsie
 [ - ]  x11-common


Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

This sounds like your network / router issue. In any case, tun the three commands @waltinator has asked for above. Then edit your question and copy the output of the commands from the terminal directly into your question above. Finally format the pasted output as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.

Put the output log in the question. The first promt, sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager spits out a 550 line log, full of my ip and mac adresses.
